# Чи є помилкою вживання «як правило»?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи є помилкою вживання «як правило»? Знаходжу інформацію, що замість цієї конструкції можна вживати «зазвичай», але щодо правильності вислову «як правило» нічого конкретного немає. Допоможіть розібратися.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Підійти до відповіді на це питання варто з кількох боків.

По-перше, [СУМ](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE) дає таке пояснення:

> ◊ Як пра́вило у знач. вставн. сл. — здебільшого, у переважній
>   більшості випадків. Дума — це віршований твір, виконуваний (як
>   правило, соло) речитативом (Рильський, IX, 1962, 225).

Але ми добре знаємо, що в СУМі мови зближували з іншими мовами (а у дорадянському словнику Гринченка, наприклад, такого вислову ще не бачимо), тому подивимось в інших джерелах.

Так, у [«Як ми говоримо»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53407/33176.html) Антоненка-Давидовича пише:

> За відповідник до **російського** вислову как правило в нас дуже
>   вподобали вислів **як правило**, запозичений з інших мов і насамперед із
>   **російської**: «Усі будиночки були двоповерхові, розраховані, **як правило**,
>   на дві сім’ї». А тим часом наша мова має свої ориґінальні
>   відповідники, про які часто забувають: **як звичайно** («На есмінці, як
>   звичайно, в цей час панувала тиша. — М. Трублаїні), **як водиться** («Раз
>   ласуни, **як водиться** у них, поснідать добре захотіли». — Л. Глібов), **як
>   заведено** («У кіно, як заведено в нас, ходимо ми, дівчата, всі разом».
>   Із живих уст). Не слід забувати цих давно відомих висловів.

Гардкорні лінґвісти з [online corrector'a](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE/) так само закликають:

> Замініть **скальковане** вставне слово як правило на стилістично кращий
>   варіант: **зазвичай, здебільшого, переважно**.
>
> НЕ РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО: Знакові голи, як правило, даються складно.
>
> РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО: Знакові голи зазвичай (здебільшого) даються складно.

Можна зробити обережний **висновок**:

Хоча вислів "як правило" є висловом словниковим, не варто зловживати ним на письмі, бо це збіднює мову, в якій присутні аналоґічні автентичні вислови. Водночас, зовсім не обов’язково повністю відмовлятися від цього вислову, адже бачимо, що ще в часи Антоненка-Давидовича він прижився серед людей. Не кожна калька є зло, але кожне зловживання нею точно злом є.

Comment: Прижився [ще до Антоненка-Давидовича](//www.google.com/search?q=%22як+правило%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1920&num=100).

Comment: До речі, [«Правопис» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/) вживає оце «як правило» 6 разів (5 у першому розділі і 1 у другому).